# if/else in magento product custom option section

Tags: php, magento

Hi I want to know if magento has the following option in the custom options section of each product:

I have a logo upload option which we have a setup fee of £20, as this isn't a recurring fee i dont want the user to pay multiple times so basically the function to say:

if client doesn't have a logo uploaded or on file with us then show logo option (another option within custom options section) and add the price associated with this option to total else do not show this option.

Answer (score 0):

There is not normally an option for this, but as long as the option is not required, there's no reason you couldn't use some CSS / JS to accomplish it. Create a helper method for `hasUploadedLogo` or something to that effect, then add a class to your productInfo div depending on whether that returns true or not. Then, use CSS to target the option div if they *don't* have a logo and hide it.